# Align elements according to chosen select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen, twitter-bootstrap-2

I use Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 and [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for select boxes. I would like to ask how can i align other elements according to box with selected items.

In this screenshot you can see two select boxes and content(elements) under select boxes.

[image]

When I select some items, the box overlaps header "Source" and items under the box. I would like to align elements down when some options are selected and align items up (back) when the options are deselected.

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b71e7w3k/1/)

**html**

```
    <div id="filter">

<div id="personFilter" class="form-group">

                    <h4> Person filter </h4>

                    <div id="personFilterContain">

                      <h5> Contain </h5>

                      <select data-placeholder= "address" 
                              name="personContainSelect" multiple class="selectPerson"><option value="0"> </option><option value="2">rogelio.francis@gmail.com</option><option value="3">meredith.sullivan@gmail.com</option><option value="4">essie.castro@gmail.com</option><option value="5">arnold.clayton@gmail.com</option><option value="6">eugene.jefferson@gmail.com</option><option value="7">ora.gibbs@gmail.com</option><option value="8">katherine.frank@gmail.com</option><option value="9">preston.goodwin@gmail.com</option><option value="10">edna.burke@gmail.com</option></select>

                    </div>

                    <div id="personFilterNotContain">

                      <h5> Dont contain </h5>

                      <select data-placeholder="address" 
                              tabindex="4" name="personNotContainSelect" multiple class="selectPerson"><option value="0"> </option><option value="2">rogelio.francis@gmail.com</option><option value="3">meredith.sullivan@gmail.com</option><option value="4">essie.castro@gmail.com</option><option value="5">arnold.clayton@gmail.com</option><option value="6">eugene.jefferson@gmail.com</option><option value="7">ora.gibbs@gmail.com</option><option value="8">katherine.frank@gmail.com</option><option value="9">preston.goodwin@gmail.com</option><option value="10">edna.burke@gmail.com</option></select>

                    </div>

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="personCheckBox"> Apply
                        </label>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- ********************* Source Filter ********************* -->

                <div id="sourceFilter" class="form-group">

                <h4> Source </h4>

                    <div id="sourceFilterSource">

                      <label class="checkbox inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sourceMailCheckBox"> Mail
                      </label>

                      <label class="checkbox inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sourcePhoneCheckBox"> Phone
                      </label>

                      <label class="checkbox inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sourceDiscussionCheckBox"> Discussion
                      </label>

                    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('select[name=personNotContainSelect]', this).chosen();
    $('select[name=personContainSelect]', this).chosen();
});
</script>
```

**css**

```
#filter{
    text-align: center;
}

#filter, #details{
  overflow: auto;
}

#filter h4{
  text-align: left;
}

#personFilter, #sourceFilter{
    width: 535px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

#personFilter{
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#personFilter h5{
  max-width: 200px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#personFilter select{
    width: 250px;
}

#personFilter div{
  display: inline-block;
}

#personFilterContain{
  max-width: 400px;
  float:left;
}

#personFilterNotContain{
  max-width: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#personFilter label:last-child{
  width: 0;
}

#personFilter .chosen-container{
  top:-30px;
}

#personFilter .checkbox{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

#sourceFilter {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 21px;
    position: relative;
}

#sourceFilterSource{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: removing height for `#personalFilter`: http://jsfiddle.net/b71e7w3k/2/ ???  Or use min-height instead http://jsfiddle.net/b71e7w3k/3/ ???

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for help, it could be part of solution, but i forgot to mention "align elements up (back) when options are deselected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set ID attr for select (e.g. test):

```
<select id="test" data-placeholder= "address"...
 ...
</select>
```

add change event. pay attention on #test_chosen, similar ID att from `<select>`. suffix _chosen added by plugin.

```
$('select[name=personContainSelect]', this).chosen().change(function(){           
        var h=$('#test_chosen').height()
        h+=56;//init height of chosen            
        $('#personFilter').height(h)
    });
```

**SOLUTION 2:** CSS

```
#personFilter{
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, I wondered its possible to solve it by css, but this is also another way.

Comment: chek solution 2 in my answer